# How to solve pumping lemma questions?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

I am trying to prove that L = { a<sup>N</sup>b<sup>M</sup>a<sup>N-M</sup>|N>=M>=0} is not regular using the pumping lemma.

I am pretty confused how to solve this.  What I have so far (which I am not sure is right) is:

Assume L is regular.  Let p>=1 be the pumping length.  Then by the pumping lemma there exists p|=1.  Consider the string s=a<sup>p+1</sup>b<sup>p</sup>a<sup>p+1-p</sup>

From the pumping lemma we know:
1. s=xyz
2. y!= ϵ
3. |xy|<=p
4. for i>=0, xyz ϵ L

Then, sϵL and |s|=(p+1)+(p)+(p+1-p) = 2p+2>=p (I'm not sure that this is true though...)

By 1, s can be written as s=xyz.  Since 3, |xy|<=p the string y contains only a's (How does this actually prove that y only contains a's?)

Since y!=ϵ, y contains at least 1 a.

I am unsure as to how to solve from here.  Am I on the right track?  I don't really understand how to proceed from this point or if my reasoning up to this point is correct.   Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This board supports LaTeX. Can you please edit your post to include LaTeX where appropriate? It will make your post easier to read: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with $a^{p+1}$ automatically qualifies your $|xy| > p$, which is invalid. So let $p$ be the pumping length, and we want $|xy| \leq p$.

Let $a^{n}b^{m}a^{n-m} \in L$ be your string. Suppose $n + m \leq p$. So let $x = a^{n}$ and $y = b^{m}$. Now try pumping $(b^{m})^{i}$. Where is your contradiction?

Similarly, consider $x = a^{n-1}$ for $k < a$ and $y = ab^{m}$. Now pump $y$. Again, you get a contradiction when looking at $a^{n-m}$.

The intuition behind the pumping lemma is that FSA cannot count; and so, any language with a requiring you to count something (like this language or $L = \{ 0^{n} 1^{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \})$ will not be regular.

Comment: How can we suppose that n+m<=p?  Or are we just saying this because we are trying to prove by contradiction since we know n>=m?  Also, when pumping (b^m)^i, I'm not sure how this shows contradiction?

Comment: The strings we choose are a necessary condition, not a sufficient condition. That means we have to act within the constraints. So by the second condition of the pumping lemma, $|xy| \leq p$. What are our options for $x$ and $y$ such that $|xy| \leq p$ and $y \neq \epsilon$. Pumping the string then gives us $a^{x}b^{y}a^{n-m}$, where $n - m \neq x - y$. Thus, the contradiction. Also, a side note- please consider using LaTeX rather than HTML to format your posts. It makes it much easier for us to read. :-)

Comment: sorry I'm trying to figure out latex but from the link http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference it appears just using ^ for superscripts should work so I'm not sure how to do it.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Surround your math with a dollar sign on either side. Think of dollar signs as math tags. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Sarah, you're on the right track. Actually, you're one step away from proving the nonregularity of the language, but you have a mistake (or omission) in the expression of the pumping lemma.

> From the pumping lemma we know: 1. s=xyz 2. y!= ϵ 3. |xy|<=p **4. for i>=0, xyz ϵ L**

Your (4) should be: for $i \geq 0, xy^iz\in L$

> By 1, s can be written as s=xyz. Since 3, |xy|<=p the string y contains only a's (How does this actually prove that y only contains a's?)

Well, the string $s$ you've chosen is $a^{p+1}b^pa^{p+1-p}$, or simply $a^{p+1}b^pa$. Then, since $|xy| \leq p$, all of the symbols in both $x$ and $y$ must come from the first $p$ symbols in $s$. What are they?

Now, using the fourth step with different values for $i$, what kind of strings do you get? Do they remain in the same language $L$?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I've been having a hard time trying to wrap my head around the pumping lemma